# Can an extra internal refrigerator light increase the vitamin C content of fruit?

Tags: nutrition, vitamins, fruit

My wife yesterday bought a new refrigerator for our house. She choose a refrigerator which within the [sales blurb](http://ehaier.com/product/2132.html) has the following claim.

> **光波增鲜**
>   生成5种仿自然光波，让采摘后的果蔬继续光合作用，叶绿素、VC含量比存放普通冰箱高30%以上。

Translating that into English we get:

> **Fresh by light**
>   Generate five kinds of imitation of natural light, picking fruits and vegetables to continue photosynthesis, chlorophyll, vitamin C content is increased up to 30 percent higher than the storage ordinary refrigerator.

I am skeptical of this claim. Can light increase the vitamin C content of fruit stored in the refrigerator by up to 30% compared to keeping the fruit in a dark refrigerator?

Comment: Mitsubish Electric are selling this in Japan, with [similar claims](http://www.lef.org/news/LefDailyNews.htm?NewsID=2072&Section=VITAMINS). LG market this in some regions as "Vita Light".

Comment: @Rincewind42 I hope I was correct in my edit (I'm assuming the technology is to have an always-on light inside the fridge). I kept misreading the title to assume it was all to do with a normal light that turns on when the door is opened.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but suggests the claim is more plausible than I thought: http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2013/06/20/the-cabbage-in-your-fridge-still-runs-on-a-daily-clock/

Answer (score 2):

## Update #1:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17556807

> Dark storage limited the decrease in juice asparagine to some extent. Aromatic lactones, such as gamma-decalactone and gamma-dodecalactone, both in skin and in flesh tissues increased more rapidly when the fruits were stored under a light condition, irrespective of fruit harvest stage. From these results, **we conclude that fruit storage under a light condition is better for fruit quality of the 'Hakuho' peaches than storage in darkness.**

http://naldc.nal.usda.gov/download/17907/PDF

> [...]**These results indicate that postharvest application of UV-C radiation can decrease decay caused by ripe rot in blueberries and may enhance antioxidant levels.**

Review papers:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3536313

http://openagricola.nal.usda.gov/Record/FNI86010719

http://openagricola.nal.usda.gov/Record/FNI86011422

> The current status of research on the application of ionizing radiation for improving the storage of temperate fruits, i.e., apple, pear, peach, nectarine, apricot, cherry, plum, strawberry, bilberry, cranberry, raspberry, and black currant, is reviewed. Changes in fruit metabolism, chemical composition, texture, and organoleptic quality attributes are discussed with reference to the irradiation dose. The feasibility of using radiation either alone or in conjunction with heat treatment, refrigeration, and controlled atmospheres (CA) for the control of storage decay caused by fungal pathogens is considered. Areas of further research are suggested before irradiation could be considered for practical application in some of these temperate fruits. The recent trends in the possible use of irradiation for disinfestation of certain pome and stone fruits and the prospects for the commercial utilization of irradiation for improving the market life of strawberries are discussed.

Nevertheless, I've contacted LG Support and asked for explanations concerning the more technical aspects of their various light technologies for fruit/vegetable storage, and I'll update this post once I receive their answer.

### - Edit -

Well, LG support never got back to me, so I can only be more distrustful to their claims.

## Old answer:

http://pharmacie.hug-ge.ch/rd/posters/espen09_gb_vitc.pdf

> Similarly, vitamin C degradation was reduced in IV administration sets stored in the
> dark compared with IV administration sets stored in the ambient light or under an UV lamp

http://www.clinchem.org/content/50/1/135.full

> When solutions of multivitamin preparations (MVPs) are exposed to light, H2O2 as well as organic peroxides are generated and the concentration of vitamin C decreases.

Of course, this study focuses on byproducts of Vitamin C, but for our needs (Vitamin C) it's a good enough source.

http://www.lg.com/ae/microsite/healthyliving/products-refrigerator.swf

> Green Tea Ions

I mean, seriously now...?

Someone should ask Mitsubishi and LG for some scientific references for their claims. To me, it looks like marketing bull.

Comment: The two studies look at vitamin C when in a solution. This however, is not the same as when the vitamin C is inside a living entity such as fruit or some vegetables.

Comment: Most papers either focus on various aspects of fruit quality preservation, or the reaction of acids and other substances in vitro, so it's not probable to find an answer focused on vitamin C. Nevertheless, I've made a query to LG Support and I'll update you once I receive an answer.